# Horizontal alignment in Tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I get the three elements on each line to space out appropriately to the end of the box??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile,tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{silence}% http://ctan.org/pkg/silence
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,intersections,calc,matrix,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{1.0\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, grow=right, sloped,dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.5pt}]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=08cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]

\node(A)[] {N=1000}
child {node[text opacity=100, align=center,draw=black!100, text width=155] {
(-50\%) \\ 
N=100 \euro4.88$\mu$ (1.96) \\
N=1000 \euro5.66$\mu$ (1.96)
}
edge from parent node[below] {}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like you forgot to include the question...

Comment: and the MWE does not work for me (Undefined control sequence.)

Comment: Apologies. Fixed now.

Comment: What do you mean by 'spaced out appropriately to the end of the box'? To remove the extra white space just remove `text width=155`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick and easy way-- you can use an `\hfill` to make expanding space:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, grow=right]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=10cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]

\node(A) {N=1000}
    child {node[align=center,draw, text width=155]
        {
        $ (-50\%) $ \\
        N=100 \hfill \euro4.88$\mu$ \hfill(1.96) \\
        N=1000 \hfill \euro5.66$\mu$ \hfill  (1.96) \\ 
        } {}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This will give you:

[image: with hfill]

You can use a `matrix of nodes` for more complicated alignments:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,matrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, grow=right]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=10cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]

\node(A) {N=1000}
    child {node[matrix,matrix of nodes,draw,ampersand replacement=\&,
        every node/.style={text width=20mm}] 
            {
            \node{};    \&  \node[align=center]{$ (-50\%) $};   \&  \node{};    \\
            \node{$N=100$ }; \& \node[align=center]{\euro4.88$\mu$}; \& \node[align=right]{(1.96)}; \\
            \node{$ N=1000 $}; \& \node[align=center]{\euro5.66$\mu$}; \& \node[align=right]{(1.96)}; \\
            \node{$ N=100,000 $}; \& \node[align=center]{\euro5.66$\mu$}; \& \node[align=right]{(1.96)}; \\
            }
        {}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: with matrix of nodes]

Comment: Is there any way I can align them by specifying tabs? If the N=1000 becomes N=100,000 the alignment will be off.

Comment: I don't know if tabs will work, but you can use a matrix of nodes.  I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to declare `tabulars` inside `nodes`, with a convenient alignments in left and right columns, you can get the desired result.

Note: I've respected the relation between values and units used by [kmacinnis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146202/1952), although I'm not sure about its correctness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile,tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{silence}% http://ctan.org/pkg/silence
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,intersections,calc,matrix,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{1.0\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, grow=right, sloped,dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.5pt}]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=08cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]

\node(A)[] {N=1000}
child {node[text opacity=100, align=center,draw=black!100] {\begin{tabular}{@{}lcr@{}}
&(-50\%)& \\ 
N=100 &\euro4.88$\mu$& (1.96) \\
N=1000 &\euro5.66$\mu$& (1.96)
\end{tabular}}
edge from parent node[below] {}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]